# objc_startCollectorThread() implicit declaration warning

Tags: objective-c, garbage-collection

I'm trying to work through Apple's [CoreData Utility Tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataUtilityTutorial/Articles/00_introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001800-CH202-TP1).  It asks me to create a 'Foundation Tool' project in the 'Command Line Utility' section.  In XCode 3.2, I only found a 'Command Line Tool' section with a 'Foundation' type in the 'New Project' wizard.

So I created the 'Command Line Tool' 'Foundation' type project, and added the following line to enable garbage collection:

```
objc_startCollectorThread();
```

I also changed the 'Objective-C Garbage Collection' setting in my 'Target Info' 'Build' tab to 'Required [-fobjc-gc-only]'.  When I run my build, I get the following error:

> warning: implicit declaration of function 'objc_startCollectorThread'

The target runs fine so far.  All it does is print 'Hello World' to the console.  I'm just concerned about this warning.  I must be doing something wrong if I'm getting warnings for something as basic as garbage collection on a command line tool.

Comment: I thought community wiki meant others could edit the question.

Comment: What are good resources besides stackoverflow for objc questions?  I googled for 10 minutes about this, and I would think that something this simple would be easily found on google.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question, I had exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should `#include <objc/objc-auto.h>`, which is where this function is defined.

Comment: Or **`#import`** instead. Either way, +1 for the good answer.

Comment: I think the typical convention is to `#include` C headers (like this one) and `#import` Objective-C headers.